# iis can't use symbol & in regex pattern

Tags: regex, iis

i try to write rule, thats skip symbol & in querystring.
For, that i wrote the following rule:

```
<rule name="skip-firt parametr" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^page1/"/>
  <conditions>
     <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="id=([0-9]+)\&?(.*)"/>
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="page2/{C:1}/?{C:2}" appendQueryString="true"/>
</rule>
```

But i have following error, when i try open resource

```
Config Error    Configuration file is not well-formed XML
```

When I remove '&' from pattern rule works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix that by replacing `&` with `&amp;`.

Comment: I'm glad that helped you :) Mark the answer as accepted if you think this is the best answer of your question.